# What happens when an Exception is thrown by main?

Tags: java, exception, jvm

Consider this code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        mayFail();
        System.out.println("This shouldn't run");
    }

    public static void mayFail() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception();
    }

}
```

I know `main` will terminate when the `Exception` is `throw`'n.

What I want to know is is there some king of a procedure in the `JVM`(or anywhere) that executes when this happens?

**EDIT:**

After reading almas shaikh answer I managed to handle this `Exception` like so:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UncaughtExceptionHandler a = new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Uncaught Exception");
            }
        };

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(a);

        mayFail();
        System.out.println("This shouldn't run");
    }

    public static void mayFail() throws Exception{
        throw new Exception();
    }

}
```

So if I understand it correctly this is as far is it goes? And without the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` the program just terminates without doing anything really?

Comment: @Charlie You didn't understood my question.

Comment: That's why I deleted my comment :I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default even main is executed as a thread and default threadGroup's `uncaughtException` method is executed. If you have explicitely defined your custom [uncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) and registered it, then it's that what's going to be called.

Post that you are out of thread and your main terminates its execution and if main is the only non daemon thread that's running, then your java process will terminate as well.

Comment: Interesting, I messed with that a bit and updated my question. So is this really as far is it goes? and nothing really happens if I haven't explicitly defined an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Comment: No. It will terminate the JVM gracefully irrespective of whether you have uncaughtException handler or not. This was with respect to your question "What I want to know is is there some king of a procedure in the JVM(or anywhere) that executes when this happens"

Comment: Ohh I know it will terminate ether way, I was just wondering if there wore some external(not written by me) procedure that was invoked in that case.

Comment: No if you want to make your main thread handle all exception catch all type of exception like `try { ...}catch(Exception e) {..}`

Comment: Obviously it's the right way of catching. I asked only out of curiosity.

Comment: `main` is just a normal function, except it gets called to start a java program, so there's no special procedure invoked when it throws an exception.